# Who portrayed the editor of the Havard Crimson in A Small Circle of Friends (1980)?

Tags: credits

Aren't there cast lists saying who portrayed the editor?

Yes there are.  For example, the cast list in Internet Movie Database (IMDB) lists:

> David Hollander   ... Editor of 'Crimson'

[https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081528/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1[1]](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081528/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1%5B1%5D)

And the IMDB list of acting credits of David hollander (I) also lists him as the editor of Crimson.

https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0390873/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0#actor

So there should be no problem, right?

Except that David Hollander (I), a rather busy and well known actor in 1980, was born on August 7, 1969, according to his IMDB page, and should have been only nine when *A Small Circle of Friends* (1980) was filmed - in March, 1979 according to IMDB.

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081528/locations?ref_=ttrel_sa_4

Nine-year-old college students are quite rare, even in movies and tv.

Thus I suspect some sort of error or mistaken identity in the cast lists for *A Small Circle of Friends*, similar to the way that one reference book listed Adam Hollander (1964-1984) as a member of the production crew of *J.W. Coop* (1971), even though that was actually Adam Holender (b. 1937), as their IMDB pages show.

So does anyone know, or can find out, who portrayed the editor of the Crimson in *A Small Circle of Friends* (1980)?

Added sept. 4, 2021.

Paulie_D's answer says that the real life editor of the *Crimson* at the time  portrayed the editor in the movie, and that his name was also David Hollander.

That sounds reasonable - very few person have ever had unique names.

For example, IMDB also lists a David Hollander (II), born May 16, 1968, as a producer, writer, and director, though with no acting roles.

And if you google "David N Hollander, Harvard Crimson" you will find several links to *Crimson* articles written by David N. Hollander.

[https://search.yahoo.com/search?fr=mcafee&type=E211US105G0&p=David+N.+HOllander%2C+Harvard+Crimson](https://search.yahoo.com/search?fr=mcafee&type=E211US105G0&p=David%20N.%20HOllander%2C%20Harvard%20Crimson)

But those articles are dated to the late 1960s and early 1970s.  Would David N. Hollander still be writing for the Harvard *Crimson* at least half a decade later in 1979?  Or was the person who portrayed the editor in *A Small Circle of Friends* a diferent persn from David N. Hollander?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Harvard_Crimson says that the Crimson assigns the title "editor" to almost anyone who writes for the paper.  So he may not have been *the* editor but merely *an* editor.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, it was [David Hollander](https://www.thecrimson.com/article/1971/2/8/a-parting-shot-pso-here-i/) who was the **real-life** editor of the Harvard Crimson at the time.

I only have this from a fan wiki but there was such a person

> After some filming was accomplished in and around Harvard (**including sequences featuring David Hollander, real-life editor of the Harvard Crimson at the time, as himself**), the higher-ups at the college finally learned more about the film's plot and barred the crew from filming in Harvard Yard.

Clearly IMDB has it linked incorrectly.

Comment: "At the time" could mean "at the time of the depicted events" as well as "at the time of filming".